# THREEJS - Buffer geometry with custom UV mapping

Tags: three.js

Strange behaviour happening defining UV mapping of BufferGeometry:

I understand that for indexed BufferGeometry I don't need to repeat vertices and can reuse them - so for a matrix of 10x10 pools I connect 200 triangles with 2 different textured materials.

The problem starts when I want to apply UV mapping:

```
var gg=new THREE.BufferGeometry(),vtx=[],uv=[],fc=[[],[]],mm=[
    material1,
    material2
];
for(var y=0 ; y<11 ; y++)
    for(var x=0 ; x<11 ; x++) {
        vtx.push(x-5,0,y-5);
        if(x&&y) {
            var p=(vtx.length/3)-1;
            fc[(x%2)^(y%2)].push(
            // Incides
            //    A    B     C
                p,   p-11, p-1,
                p-1, p-11, p-12
            );
            uv.push(
            // UV mapping (suppose per triangle??!)
            //    A    B    C
                1,0, 1,1, 0,1,
                0,1, 1,1, 0,0
            );
        }
    }
Array.prototype.push.apply(fc[0],fc[1]); gg.setIndex(fc[0]);
gg.addAttribute('position',new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(vtx,3));
gg.addAttribute('uv',new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(uv,2));
gg.computeVertexNormals();
gg.addGroup(0,300,0);
gg.addGroup(300,300,1);
scene.add(new THREE.Mesh(gg,mm));
```

Test link exists here: https://www.crazygao.com/vc/tst3.htm

As far as I understand, even in indexed THREE.BufferGeometry the UVs are attached to VERTEX rather than INCIDES, is it right? If it is like this, how can I achieve UV mapping per single triangle (face)? And I prefer to not create THREE.Geometry and then convert to THREE.BufferGeometry, and trying to avoid adding "extra vertex" as this is not what indexed BufferGeometry intended to do.
Setting constant UV for vertex may be a big problem for such mesh.

I am using THREEjs v.101

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you want per face mapping then you might have to duplicate vertices as well. Basically a unique vertex+normal+ uv combo for everything. Otherwise you'd need multiple index buffers, one for verts one for normals one for uvs. I tend to not worry too much about quantities of vertex data.. what really impacts performance is draw calls. Most gpus can handle > 1m vertices per frame but max out in around 300 - 1000 draw calls. I'm oversimplifying but that's a ballpark.

Comment: Yes, this is really working (active result in https://www.crazygao.com/vc/tst4.htm) but with a cost of having more vertices (can affect memory in more complex mesh?) and the length here is not per variables, but per vertices, so remain 300.